# Button event using dont work with Blazor Server

Tags: blazor

I had a problem with @onclick events placed on buttons in the blazor. This way:

```
<button @onclick = "(e => SelectProduct (product.Id))" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "# productModal" class = "btn btn-primary"> More Info </button>
```

So to solve it I just changed the event to the  tag
Using the same button class it looks the same and the event is triggered correctly.

```
<a @onclick="(e => SelectProduct (product.Id)) "data-toggle =" modal "data-target =" # productModal "class =" btn btn-primary "> More Info </a>
```

I hope it helps someone

Comment: What problem did you have? The button should work fine.

Comment: when i use 
`
<button @onclick = "(e => SelectProduct (product.Id))" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "# productModal" class = "btn btn-primary"> More Info </button
`
the click event dont firing

Comment: Don't include the answer in the question itself, if you think you have answer to your question then add it as an answer. To know how to ask questions see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Rodrigo it should. Can you recreate this in something you can share so I can have a look?

Comment: @HeisAif 

Yes I understand. However, the stackoverflow was preventing me from posting answers and as I saw that a user had this question, I decided to post the answer as a question, as this was the only option available at the moment!

Thanks for commenting!